# How to animate points on an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot

I have the pixel locations of `P` points on a -constant- image, for `T` iterations of an algorithm, so `locations = [T x 2*P] double`.

Now I want to create an animation where it plots the image, then plots the points, pauses for `N` seconds and updates their location to the next step. I don't know if there is a standard way to follow. I think I need something like:

```
figure;
imshow(img);
hold on;
for t=1:T
    anim = updatePlot(locations(t,:), anim); % ? 
end
```

How can I implement this `updatePlot` function?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: At each update, did you want only the current set of points to be displayed, or do you want all of the points previously seen up until the current point to be displayed? Specifically, let's say we have a point at time `t-1`.  At time `t`, do you want the points at time `t-1` to disappear and only the points at time `t` to be visible?

Comment: I only want `points(t,:)` to appear, yes, I want the ones before removed. But it could also be very nice if I can add a transition effect (like fade, or interpolation), this will be a project demonstration so as "pretty" as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of different ways. The first way would be to give the plotted points a handle so that you can delete them before the next iteration:

```
figure
imshow(img);
hold on;
for t = 1:T
    % delete the previous points plotted (skip t = 1 since they won't exist)
    if t > 1
        delete(hPoints);
    end
    hPoints = plot(xLocations(t,:),yLocations(t,:),'.');
    getframe;
    pause(N);
end
```

(I am not exactly sure how you parse your locations along each row to separate the x and y components, so I've just used `xLocations` and `yLocations` to represent those values.)

The second way would be to re-draw the entire image at each iteration:

```
figure
for t = 1:T
    clf;
    imshow(img);
    hold on;
    plot(xLocations(t,:),yLocations(t,:),'.');
    getframe;
    pause(N);
end
```

Note that `imshow` might have its own `getframe` effect so that you'll see the image flicker before plotting the points -- if that happens just switch from `imshow` to `image`.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian. handles are probably what I look for. But I wonder if we can add a transition effect too. I'm accepting your answer anyway, but future users: please don't hesitate to suggest ways for transitions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by transition? Your comment made me realize I forgot to include the pause for N seconds, which can be done using `pause(N)` -- I've edited the answer appropriately. What kind of transition effect are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure actually :) I just want to make a nice presentation/demo. One basic thing could be `points(t)` fades out and `points(t+1)` fades in. Or each point can "move" gradually to the next location. Just to make people watch the process better.

Comment: That is definitely possible but it gets trickier and trickier to do more complex transitions. Fading is difficult with points since I don't believe they have a transparency (alpha) setting. Having the points move gradually just means adding new points to plot -- MATLAB does not do transitions like MS PowerPoint.